# How To Switch To A Frame That Appears As A Pop Up Window

Tags: c#, popup, selenium-webdriver, window, frame

I am using the following applications:

- Selenium 2.0 in C#
- Firefox

I need to write a test that clicks a button and opens a frame as a pop up window. The frame does not have a name nor id.

The source code in the frame starts with "html" instead of "frame". However, when you right click on the window, it shows that it is a frame. So, I think it is a frame instead of a window.

I have tried the following code, but does not work:

- driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0)

The error I get looks like below:

> error: No response from server for url `http://localhost:7055/hub/session/126a4485-48cb-4230-b0b0-69c4169b1852/element/%7B706f4a88-56a7-4813-af1b-8e137ce676af%7D/click`

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to find element in Selenium WebDriver By Name and XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727617/unable-to-find-element-in-selenium-webdriver-by-name-and-xpath)

Answer (score 0):

Try this Syntax may not be correct but try this logic.

```
 WebElement MyFrame =  driver.FindElement(By.Id("frame"));
 driver.SwitchTo().Frame(MyFrame)
```

It was useful for me in Java.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried your way, but still no success. I am getting the following error: error: No response from server for url http://localhost:7055/hub/session/73914c61-25d9-4dc7-9481-7fd84aae5d97/element/%7B11b0e937-3d20-4b9e-b53d-51274147f940%7D/click

Comment: Sorry, but If It does not start with Frame tag then you should not use switchTo. Just Use the Xpath i.e Complete Xpath. Use Firebug or something else to get Xpath. Are you able to find the same using IDE and Not with Webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple.  First of all, a iframe or frame can't "appear as a popup window".  What you probably mean is that a separate popup window opens with its own window handle and it has its own embedded iframe?  If so, just use driver.switchTo.window( handle ) before you try to access its frame by ANOTHER call to driver.switchTo.frame(0).   This is followed by driver.findElement(By) and whatever else you need to act upon.

```
void switchToPopupWithClickAndClose() {
    driver.switchTo.window( handle );
    driver.switchTo.frame(0);
    driver.findElement(By.id("elId") ).click();

    if ( driver.getWindowHandles().size() > 1 ) {//popup still open
       driver.switchTo.defaultContent();
       driver.close();
       driver.switchTo().defaultContent();// switch to default content of 
                                      // original window
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's an old post but still valid for me because I got stuck no a pop-up frame as well. Problem is, once the pop-up appears, I count the number of windows:

```
int windows = driver.WindowHandles.Count();
```

before and after popup the number of windows is 1.

The number of frames:

```
int totalframes = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("iframe")).Count();
```

is 2 before and after pop-up. So it looks as if the frame is already there, in the page, only hidden until triggered. The pop-up appears as a separate window (where you select the type of file you want to export a report into). I cannot get to the elements in that new window, however I try to switch between frames.