# FindElement by Name Fails but by Xpath Succeeds?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, junit4

This doesn't make any sense to me. Here is the source code of the page element I'm trying to intereact with:

```
<li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="includeStudents" value="true" checked />
     <span style="cursor: pointer;"
          onclick="javascript:checkBoxSingleClick(document.userSearchForm.includeStudents);"
          ondblclick="javascript:userTypeDoubleClick(document.userSearchForm, document.userSearchForm.includeStudents);">
     <strong><u>S</u>tudent</strong>
       </span>
 </li>
```

When I try to find the element using By.name - I get an element not visible error, however, when I try to find the same element using By.xpath - everything works just fine. Here is the code from my test.

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("includeStudents")));
    driver.findElement(By.name("includeStudents")).click();
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ed-userSearchCheckboxUserTypeFilter']/li[2]/input")).click();
```

I added the wait to confirm that it's not just a timing issue. I get a timeout error waiting for the visibility of the element when using by.name

What am I missing here?

Comment: Are you sure this was the only element on the page with this name? Can you try doing the following for a more proper detail?

Comment: driver.findElement(By.id("ed-userSearchCheckboxUserTypeFilter")).findElement(By.name("includeStudents")).click();

Comment: Interesting - I tried your line and it works - TY. I'm curious now - based on your first comment I am assuming the thought is there's another element using that name (was my initial thought as well). But a search on the page source code didn't bring one up. Also, the "wait" times out indicating (to me) that no element with that name is located - even though the page is fully loaded

Comment: Well that's odd. Because yes, indeed my line of thought was that. You could always do a findElements() on that locator and get a count of it, not sure although if there are issues on the <li> element.

Comment: You can always join #selenium on freenode (IRC), and try to get a better answer from the guys over there too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to find element in Selenium WebDriver By Name and XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727617/unable-to-find-element-in-selenium-webdriver-by-name-and-xpath)

Answer (score 2):

I might be completely off here, but have you checked to see if that element is not in the parent of the webdrivers instance?  For example if your code is located inside of a frame that you have not yet stepped into, then it will not be able to locate the Xpath. It will throw an error that no element is present and the webdriver timed out after x seconds.

```
driver.switchTo().frame("MyElementFrame");    
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ed-userSearchCheckboxUserTypeFilter']/li[2]/input")).click();
```