# Find element in Selenium using XPATH or CSS Selector

Tags: c#, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I m trying to find the element "import" using Selenium Webdriver in C#. Have tried the following codes but nothing find it.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='menu_bg']/ul/li[3]")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@id='import']/a")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#import>a")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//*[@class='menu_bg']/ul/li[3]/a")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("ul[@class='menu_bg']>li[value='3']")).Click();
```

Please help me out. Design page looks like below:

```
<body>
    <div class="header_bg"></div>
    <div class="menu_bg">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li id="retrieve"></li>
            <li id="scan" class="test"></li>
            <li id="import">
                <a target="main" href="import/import.aspx" onclick="clickme(this,'import')">Import</a>
            </li>
            <li id="admin"></li>
            <li id="help"></li>
            <li style="float: right;"></li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</body>
```

All the time I got the error as below:

```
unable to find the element
```

Comment: Give a try for: driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//li[@id='import']/a")).Click();

Comment: You can also try: driver.FindElement(By.id("import")).Click();

Answer (score 3):

XPath indexers are 1-based, as opposed to most other languages whereby they are 0-based.

This means you are actually targetting the **2nd** `li` element, which has no `anchor` element.

So:

```
//*[@class='menu_bg']/ul/li[3]/a
```

However, this XPath query is not great and is too strict on position - thus although this newly fixed XPath above *should* work, I'd advise you to think of something else.

Comment: +1, for pointing out XPaths like this one should be avoided in the first place.

Comment: @Arran: Thanks for your suggestion. But still i got the below error - Unable to find element with xpath == //*[@class='menu_bg']/ul/li[3]/a

Answer (score 1):

By reviewing this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727617/unable-to-find-element-in-selenium-webdriver-by-name-and-xpath/)(Thanks to @Arran), the above issue was fixed. 'switching' to the current IFrame directs Selenium to show any requests to that frame instead.

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame()
```

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't show us the page had any IFrames in it so we couldn't have possibly have known this would solve the issue. Nonetheless, glad you got it solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by chaining Selenium 'FindElement' like so;

`driver.FindElement(By.Id("import")).FindElement(By.TagName("a"));`
which will give you the child of the element with ID that has a tag of 'a'.

Another way you could do this is by casting your `Driver` to an `IJavascriptExecutor` and executing javascript directly in the browser using a JQuery selector. I find this better for more complex Selenium lookups;

`((IJavascriptExecutor)Driver).ExecuteScript("$("a[target='main'][href='import/import.aspx'])").click();`