# selenium css selector or xpath for complex class doesn't work when run as script

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors, automated-tests

The following code, which extracts elements using css selector, works in the ipython3 terminal, but doesn't find the elements when run as script:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = scrape_url + "&keywords=" + keyword
driver.get(url)
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".search-result.search-result__occluded-item.ember-view")
```

The complex class of the element:

```
"search-result search-result__occluded-item ember-view"
```

The following xpath worked in the terminal, but not as a script:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//li[contains(@class, 'search-result search-result__occluded-item')]")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a timing issue: required element could be generated dynamically, so you need to wait some time until it appears in `DOM`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = scrape_url + "&keywords=" + keyword
driver.get(url)
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@class, 'search-result search-result__occluded-item')]")))
```

Also some class names could be assigned dynamically. That's why using compound name as `"search-result search-result__occluded-item ember-view"` might not work without [`ExplicitWait`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Answer (score 0):

If  you can't find any elements with selenium css selector, then can you always try to use xpath instead of the css selector.

More information about that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120263/find-element-in-selenium-using-xpath-or-css-selector).

Comment: xpath did not work either. Sorry, I will update the question

Answer (score 0):

Pass only partial class name like,

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".search-result__occluded-item")
```

Comment: Put wait before finding element.