# Selenium C# Find Both Attribute And CSS Class, Using XPath or CssSelector

Tags: c#, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

How do I find both Data QA Id and CSS Class in Selenium C# ?

Trying to locate both DataQAid attribute and also see if its class ng-invalid, (Angular Material Textbox Error)

This is what wrote so far,
Open to using CssSelector or anything else, instead of Xpath

```
private By PhoneError => By.XPath("//*[@attr.data-qa='homephone']");
```

[image]

**Resource:**
[Find element in Selenium using XPATH or CSS Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24120263/find-element-in-selenium-using-xpath-or-css-selector)

Comment: First find class object.  Then search in class object for the data-qa.

Comment: hi @jdweng feel free to write in answer, and I can send points, thanks

Comment: hi @jdweng someone placed answer below, I am going to try that, hopefully it works too, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer using CSS selectors because of the better support and speed over XPath. I've tested the below with the HTML you provided and it works.

```
private By PhoneError => By.CssSelector("input[ng-invalid][data-qa='homephone-update']");
```

Comment: so it By.CssSelector(input[ng-invalid][data-qa='homephone-update']),  can you write in final answer? and I can send points, thanks

Comment: @Artportraitdesign1 Updated answer that parallels your posted code.

Answer (score 1):

A working XPath could be :

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'mat-form-field')]/input[contains(@data-qa,'homephone-update') and contains(@class,'ng-invalid')]
```

Output : 1 node.

```
  <input _ngcontent-ng-cli-universal-cli matinput formcontrolname="homephoneNumber" placeholder="'HomePhone'" class="mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-tns-c64-42 ng-touched cdk-text-field-autofil)-monitored ng-dirty ng-invalid" maxlength="50" id="mat-input-26" data-placeholder="'Home Phone'" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="false" data-qa=" homephone-update">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `and` and `contains`=>

```cs
private By PhoneError => By.XPath("//*[@attr.data-qa='homephone' and contains(@class, ‘ng-invalid’)]");
```