# SwitchTo() Frame in Selenium with c#

Tags: c#, html, selenium, frame, frameset

I use selenium on this site, but I cant use any of its elements. Because they comes from 'frame' and its in 'frameset', here is html part;

```
 <frameset rows="0%, 95%" frameborder="0" frameSpacing="0" marginHeight="0" marginWidth="0">
                <frame id='unloadFrame' src="/somesrc" noresize>
                <frame src="/somesrc" noresize>
 </frameset>
            <noframes>
              Your browser doesn't support frames, This web site requires a frames capable browser.
            </noframes>
```

I need to access second frame which starts with src, I used this method but still cant use any element;

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(1);
Boolean sa = driver.FindElements(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_txtCustomerId")).Count > 0;
if (sa == true)
{
    driver.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_MainContent_txtCustomerId")).SendKeys("HelloWorld");
}
```

Is it because Frame(1) is not frame i want ? Or should i use different way to get into it?

Thank You

Comment: Are you sure there are no more frames on a page?

Comment: The syntax for switching to a frame looks correct. Are you sure element with `id="ctl00_MainContent_txtCustomerId"` exists in the frame?

Comment: Well i try different way to write it(maybe master page prefix) but no result

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to find element in Selenium WebDriver By Name and XPath](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727617/unable-to-find-element-in-selenium-webdriver-by-name-and-xpath)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This code will also switch to the frame with **'src' attribute as '/somesrc' and with 'id' attribute not 'unloadFrame'**

```
driver.SwitchTo().Frame(driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//frame[@src='/somesrc' and not(@id='unloadFrame')]")));
```

Comment: This is exacly what i am looking for. Thank You sir

Comment: Nope, it is cheating (joking, +1) :) Then, why `driver.SwitchTo().Frame(1);` hasn't worked?

Comment: :D Well, I also don't know. Only the OP can answer how the frame(s) are implemented in his/her app which may clear the cloud as to why **`driver.SwitchTo().Frame(1);`** didn't work. I merely provided an alternative.. I also have a hunch that **`driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);`** might work here.. Can't say for sure though, but that **id=unloadframe** is ticking me.. :)

Answer (score 2):

I am writing this simple method to enter text in Iframe.

```
public void SwitchToIframeandEnterText(IWebElement frame, 
                                     IWebElement field, string txt)
    {
        Driver.SwitchTo().Frame(frame);
        field.SendKeys(txt);
        Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
    }
```

Where,

> - IWebElement frame = Locator of Iframe
> - IWebElement field = Locator of Field where you want to enter text
> - string txt = text that you want to enter

Answer (score 2):

Switch IFrame in C# -

1. Index
2. ID or Name
3. Web Element

eg-

1. driver.SwitchTo().Frame(0);
2. driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
3. IWebElement element= driver.FindElement(By.Id("ElementID"));
4. driver.SwitchTo().ParentFrame();