# Not able to click the image button using selenium web driver in C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am in the process of automating my test using selenium. I am currently unable to click on the image button. Please see the code below

```
<input name="op-DPChoose-MAESTRO^SSL" type="image" src="/images/logos/MAESTRO.gif" alt="Maestro">
```

I am using the code below to identify the element and click.

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//img[@src ='/images/logos/MAESTRO.gif' and @alt='Maestro']")).Click();
```

Not sure what the problem is. Could somebody help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `//input` not `//img`. Other than that, your XPath should be fine

```
driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//input[@src ='/images/logos/MAESTRO.gif' and @alt='Maestro']")).Click();
```

Comment: Hi Vivek, I am getting the following message . No such element

Comment: @Tom is your input inside an iFrame? If the html provided is correct there should be no other reason the XPath in my answer doesn't find it

Comment: Yes its inside an iFrame

Comment: See this helpful answer. You'll need to switch into the iFrame first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14727617/unable-to-find-element-in-selenium-webdriver-by-name-and-xpath/